# How to use a for-in loop for an array of string APIs and using each API link to parse the same JSON structure in Swift in Xcode

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, for-in-loop

I have an array of strings that contain API links. Here's an example

```
var apiLinkArray  = [String]()
apiLinkArray = ["google.com/link1", "google.com/link2" , "google.com/link3"]
```

I am trying to use a for-in loop to take out a single API string and parse the JSON

```
for count in 0...self.apiLinkArray.count-1 {
    // Pre Code
    let specificUrl = self.apiLinkArray[count]
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: specificUrl)!) {(data, response, error) in
        do {
        // JSON Parsing Stuff
        } catch {
        }
    }.resume()
    
    // Other outside code
}
```

The issue I am facing is that the for-in loop will run without running the URLSession stuff then in the end it will run URLSession stuff. For example, the loop will begin and do the "pre Code" then it reaches URLSession and skips it and does "other outside code" then it will go back and do URLSession. This causes a lot of problems especially if the apiLinkArray contains 40-50 APIs. For me, when it goes back to URLSession the API links are in the wrong order compared to the array in the beginning. So, is there a way that when the for-in loop begins, it will do the "pre Code" then the URLSession with the do function then it will run the "other outside code" then it will loop again changing "count" to 1 and doing the loop again? Thanks.

Comment: You want to make 50 api calls one after the other? An app should not have this many api calls on one screen. Even if it has, it should be handled properly with a completion handler and in a way that it doesn't affect the user experience. I would suggest you to read about `Asyncronous Functions` and `Completion Handlers`

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com I have been reading what you mentioned on Asynchronous Functions and competition handlers but how do I do that in a for-in loop because won't I be received the data from the network at random times so wouldn't that cause the order of the values received be changed. Can you show me an example code of how to do this without the values coming back shuffling with each other. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Multiple async requests in order. How to wait for previous request to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428648/swift-multiple-async-requests-in-order-how-to-wait-for-previous-request-to-fin)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `URLSession.shared.dataTask` supposed to be executed asynchronously.

If your expectation is executed them one by one then return in order, take a look at Swift Operation https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/operations/.

Or implementing a naive solution:

```
let urls = [
    URL(string: "http://apple.com/1")!,
    URL(string: "http://apple.com/2")!,
]

var count = urls.count
let results = Dictionary<URL, Int>()

urls.forEach { (url: URL) in
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: $0) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        count -= 1
        // Parse your own data
        let result = ...
        results[url] = result
        
        guard count <= 0 { else return }
        // All requests are finished
    }
    .resume()
}
```